# Alternate color for list

Tags: css, html

I would like to have an alternate row color, but is color is not covering the whole role.

HTML:

```
  <div id="map-info" class="dropSheet">
    <ul class="info-lists">
        <li class="info-list">
            <address>
              <strong>Twitter Inc</strong><br>
              795 Folsom Ave, Suite 600<br>
              San Francisco, CA 94107<br>
              <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> (123) 456-7890
            </address>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#map-info
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding:20px 20px;
}

.dropSheet
{
  background-color/**/: #FFFFFF;
  background-image/**/: none;
}

.info-list
{
  list-style-type: none;
}

.info-list:nth-child(odd) { background: red; }
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uN2SW/ whats your problem the color is applied for the whole only.

Comment: `<address>` is not appropriate for all postal and e-mail addresses; it should be reserved for providing such information about the contact people for the document: http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/

Comment: alternate row color to apply but where?

Comment: @Kev Fixx did the answer helped you? Please upvote/accept the answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 2):

Case 1:

Alternate row color for `<p>` elements

```
p:nth-child(odd)
{
    color:#ff0000;
}
p:nth-child(even)
{
    color:#0000ff;
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jnsM5/)

**Case 2**

Alternate row color for `<li>` elements

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>details 1</li>
    <li>details 2</li>
    <li>details 3</li>
    <li>details 4</li>
    <li>details 5</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li { color: green; }

li:nth-child(odd) { color: red; }
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JQAvz/)